# GroupBy of a dataframe by comparison against a set of items

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

So I have a dataframe of movies with about 10K rows. Have a column that captures its genre in a comma separated string. Since a movie can be classified in multiple genres, I needed to create a set of genres that contained all possible genres in the 10K rows. So I went about it by doing as follows:

```
simplist = []
for i in df.genres.values:
    vlist = i.split(', ')
    for item in vlist:
        simplist.append(item)
gset = set(simplist)
```

This gets me a list of 24 genres from the 27K items in the simplist which is awesome. But heres the pinch:

1. I want to groupby genres by comparing genres to the set and then do aggregation and other operations AND
2. I want the output to be 24 distinct groups such that if a movie has more than one of the genres in the set - it should show up in both groups (removes sorting or tagging bias in the data gathering phase)

Is groupby even the right way to go about this?

Thanks for your input/thoughts/options/approach in advance.

Comment: Can you post a small sample input/desired output?

Comment: so the row is df.genres look something like `"val1, val2, val3"` and another row might be `"val4, val2, val5"`. There is 10K of these rows. Code block above makes it into a set that goes `val1,val2, val3,val4,val5`. Output would be to group the  df by val1 .. 24 such that  if the genre rows have any of the values that the row would show up in more than one of the val groups. I hope I am not adding to the confusion

Comment: So the output might look like this based on comaring Dataframe row value membership to the set while grouping


`val 1
    Movie 1     some aggregation or function 
    Movie 2
    Movie 3
val 2
    Movie 4
    Movie 1
    Movie 7
...
val 24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!! Wanted to thank a bunch of offline folks and Pythonistas who helped me in the right direction. Turns out I'd been spinning my wheels with sets and lists when one single Pandas command (well 3 to be precise) does the trick!!

`df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.genres.str.split(', ').tolist(), index=[df.col1, df.col2, df.coln]).stack()`
`df2 = df2.reset_index()[[0, 'col1', 'col2', 'coln',]]`
`df2.columns = ['Genre', 'col1', "col2", 'coln']`

This should create a 2nd dataframe (df2) that has the key columns for analysis from the original dataframe and the rows duplicated/attributed to each genre. You see the true value of this when you turnaround and do something like:

`revenue_table = df2.pivot_table(index=['Release Year','Genre'], values=['Profit'],aggfunc={'Profit': np.sum},fill_value=0,dropna=True)` or anything to similar effect or use case.

Closing this but would appreciate any notes on more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I made some headway but still unable to get to put the puzzle pieces together.

Started off by making a list and set (don't know which I will end up using) of unique values:

`simplist = []`

`for i in df.genres.values:
    vlist = i.split(', ')
    for item in vlist:
        simplist.append(item)`

`gset = set(simplist)
g_list = list(gset)`

Then, separately use `df.pivot` to structure the analysis:

`table7 = df.pivot_table(index=['release_year'], values=['runtime'],aggfunc={'runtime': [np.median, ], 'popularity': [np.mean]}, fill_value=0, dropna=True)`

But here's the thing:

it would be awesome if I could index by `g_list` or check `'genres'` against the `gset` of 24 distinct items but df.pivot_table does not support that. Leaving it at Genres creates ~2000 rows and is not meaningful.